# How to change default port of bitnami mongodb vm in microsoft azure

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am deploying my NodeJS web application project in Microsoft azure. I am using Bitnami MongoDB vm for my server, the default port 27017 is not secured.
Due to security reason I wanted to change some 27171, I have changed in mongo.conf file but its giving below error.

mongod.conf file-

```js
dbpath=/data/db

#where to log
logpath=/opt/bitnami/mongodb/log/mongodb.log

logappend=true

#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 27171

journal=true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
auth = true
```

The error is

```js
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
connecting to: mongodb:///opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock/
2017-04-03T13:07:48.437+0000 W NETWORK  [main] Failed to connect to /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:0, reason: No such file or directory
2017-04-03T13:07:48.462+0000 E QUERY    [main] Error: couldn't connect to server/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:234:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Not exactly sure of your error, but what do you mean, when you say that port 27017 is "not secure"? Changing port number won't change anything related to security.

Comment: Actually, in your error, it's showing an attempt to connect to 27017 still. maybe edit your question to show how you started the mongo shell? I'm guessing you didn't specify port number.

Answer (score 0):

I have test in my lab, we can use this script to change the default port:

```
root@mongodb:/# mongod --port 49000 --dbpath /data/db
```

Here is the result:

```
root@mongodb:/data/db# mongo admin --username root -p ***** --port 49000
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
connecting to: mongodb:///opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.2
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-04-04T05:20:58.801+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2017-04-04T05:20:58.801+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2017-04-04T05:20:58.801+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
> db = db.getSiblingDB('admin')
admin
> 
> 
>
```

Comment: sir am using Bitnami mongodb VM in azure, we can give port number in config file only sir. When I run mongo shell after I change port number to 27171 in config file, it is giving above error.

Comment: I use Bitnami mongodb VM in Azure too, to fix this, you should modify the configure file to 27017, then restart mongodb, then use the script to modify the default port.

Comment: As far as I know, change default port, there is no need to change configure file. please try this command `root@mongodb:/# mongod --port 49000 --dbpath /data/db`  then use this command to connect it `mongo admin --username root -p ***** --port 49000`   about the dbpath, you should create it before run command.

Comment: Sir i got your point what you are saying, If we do manually as you told, once  we close the vm(which is opened using putty) it will gone right sir. I want like once  we start the VM it should take 49000 port, Can we do that?

Comment: @Chandrashekhar close the VM? I restart the mongodb service, and the port 49000 can be connect. do you mean you restart your VM, then the port 49000 not work?

Comment: @Chandrashekhar according to the bitnami official documentation, `To connect to MongoDB from a different machine, you must open port 27017 for remote access.` it seems we can't modify the port in mongodb,conf.

Comment: @ Jason Ye - MSFTm, Sir my problem is Once we start the Mongodb VM its should run using some random port, How to do?

Comment: @Chandrashekhar sorry, for now I have not find any way to edit the port except use `mongod --port `command  .

Comment: @ Jason Ye - MSFTm, Sir if u change port using this mongod --port, if u close the VM it will lost right, again it will run on default port right sir.

Comment: @Chandrashekhar I know what you're worried about, I will checking on the query and would get back to you soon on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140040/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-chandrashekhar).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and just found the fix.
The `mongo` command isn't the normal mongo binary we have all come to love. It seems to be a custom one attempting to connect to the socket directly.

1. Change your mongodb config's port.
2. edit the custom mongo client script by running

   ```
   $ sudo vim `which mongo`
   ```
3. Here is where they call the socket directly. Change the socket port and try running it again.

   ```
   - /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
   + /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27171.sock
   ```

Here is what mine looks like after editing:

```
#!/bin/sh
LC_ALL="C"
export LC_ALL
case "$@" in
  *--host*)
    exec $0.bin "$@"
    exit
esac
exec $0.bin --host /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-28018.sock "$@"
```

Good Luck!